# For loop weird looping for drawing rectangles with Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt

[Picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWpNK.png) \\ I’m making a match 3 type of game and I now have the core game engine done, so I’m starting the UI part. *Note that this is my first try with QT, although I’ve done it with Tkinter on python.*

My **problem** is inside my 2 for loops, *comment says //Drawing the Gems,* to draw the gems on the screen. I'm going through my Gem object 6x6 array. As you can see on the image, it is not doing as intended, **the 36 gems are not being drawed** like it's supposed to. Only the first row and the first column is done, which is weird.

Thank you in advance for any help.

*(Also, I tried changing the pen color so it changes depending on which type of gem the painter is trying to draw, but it didn't work and I’m pretty sure I’m not doing it the correct way)*

```
void Interface::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{

    QPainter painter(this);
    // Pens
    QPen linepen(Qt::black);
    linepen.setWidth(2);
    QPen gempen(Qt::red);
    gempen.setWidth(4);

    // Points
    QPoint linepoint1;
    linepoint1.setX(60);
    linepoint1.setY(60);
    QPoint linepoint2;
    linepoint2.setX(420);
    linepoint2.setY(60);

    // Drawing the lines
    painter.setPen(linepen);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
    {
        painter.drawLine(linepoint1, linepoint2);
        linepoint1.setY(60 + (60 * i));
        linepoint2.setY(60 + (60 * i));
    }
    // Resetting the points
    linepoint1.setX(60);
    linepoint1.setY(60);
    linepoint2.setX(60);
    linepoint2.setY(420);
    // Drawing the columnns
    for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
    {
        painter.drawLine(linepoint1, linepoint2);
        linepoint1.setX(60 + (60 * i));
        linepoint2.setX(60 + (60 * i));
    }

    QPoint gempoint1;
    gempoint1.setX(75);
    gempoint1.setY(75);
    QPoint gempoint2;
    gempoint2.setX(105);
    gempoint2.setY(105);
    QRect gem(gempoint1, gempoint2);
    painter.setPen(gempen);

    // Drawing the gems
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            QColor color;
            if (m_gameBoard.getGem(i + 1, j + 1).getRepresentation() == "1")
            {
                color.blue();
            }
            else if (m_gameBoard.getGem(i + 1, j + 1).getRepresentation() == "2")
            {
                color.red();
            }
            else if (m_gameBoard.getGem(i + 1, j + 1).getRepresentation() == "3")
            {
                color.green();
            }
            else if (m_gameBoard.getGem(i + 1, j + 1).getRepresentation() == "4")
            {
                color.cyan();
            }
            else if (m_gameBoard.getGem(i + 1, j + 1).getRepresentation() == "5")
            {
                color.magenta();
            }
            else if (m_gameBoard.getGem(i + 1, j + 1).getRepresentation() == "6")
            {
                color.yellow();
            }
            else if (m_gameBoard.getGem(i + 1, j + 1).getRepresentation() == "7")
            {
                color.black();
            }
            else if (m_gameBoard.getGem(i + 1, j + 1).getRepresentation() == "8")
            {
                color.setNamedColor("orange");
            }
            else if (m_gameBoard.getGem(i, j).getRepresentation() == "0")
            {
                gem.setCoords(75 + (60 * (j + 1)), 75, 105 + (60 * (j + 1)), 105);
                break;
            }


            painter.drawRect(gem);

            gem.setCoords(75 + (60 * (j+1)), 75, 105 + (60 * (j+1)), 105);

        }
        gem.setCoords(75, 75 + (60 * (i+1)), 105, 105 + (60 * (i+1)));
    }




}
```

P.S. : Sorry for engrish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're setting your coordinates at the wrong time, read comments in code:

```
...
    painter.drawRect(gem);
    //This only updates the top row (the y-coord never changes)
    gem.setCoords(75 + (60 * (j+1)), 75, 105 + (60 * (j+1)), 105);

    }
    //This only updates the first column (the x-coord never changes)
    gem.setCoords(75, 75 + (60 * (i+1)), 105, 105 + (60 * (i+1)));
}
```

Do something like:

```
...
        painter.drawRect(gem);
        //This now updates both x- and y-
        gem.setCoords(75 + (60 * (j+1)), 75 + (60 * (i+1)), 105 + (60 * (j+1)), 105 + (60 * (i+1));
    
        }
        //This isn't needed
        //gem.setCoords(75, 75 + (60 * (i+1)), 105, 105 + (60 * (i+1)));
    }
```

Here your `gem.setCoords(...)` updates both the x- and y- coordinates at the same time. Also, you may want to put `painter.drawRect(gem)` after the `gem.setCoords(...)` call. One last thing, you may want to remove the `+ 1` for the `j` and `i` since your `for` loops start from 0.

## Edit

This is in response to your comment about assigning color. I would clean it up a bit as follows (FYI: I don't know Qt and I'm assuming getRepresentation returns a QString):

```
QColor color;
int representation = m_gemBoard.getGem(i + 1, j + 1).getRepresentation.ToInt();

switch(representation)
{
   case 1:
      color.blue();
      break;
   case 2:
      color.red();
      break;
   case 3:
      color.green();
      break;
   // Fill the rest in here.
}
```

You may also want to use `int` for your colors instead of strings. You could use an enum like:

```
enum MyColors
{
   Blue = 1,
   Red = 2,
   Orange = 3,
   // Fill the rest in here.
   // 0 will be a special case for you not handled in this enum.
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I agree that the drawRect should be after the setCoords.  The way the code is, you're always drawing the _previous_ gem, which seems weird.

Comment: Thanks alot mate, I will check this out when I get back home ! Also the i+1 and j+1 were for another function call, where I ask for the line number and column number as arguments, but I guess I shouldn't do that, and should use indexes instead. 

Thanks again, will let you know if I can get it to work !

Comment: Nice it worked. I'm not sure to understand why my version wasn't working though.  And is my method of setting the color incorrect or is there a cleaner way ?

Thanks again poeple !

Comment: Your version wasn't working because your inner loop only updated and drew the first column. Then your outer loop drew the first row. If you use the debugger and step through the code you'll see how `i` and `j` are updating. Your color code isn't bad but if you wanted to clean it up then check my edit.